# Adding +1 to a URL whilst scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

If I have a url called youtube.com/user/1/ and I want the number to incrament to youtube.com/user/2/
whilst scraping the whole page, how would I do so? I've been trying to think of some ways to do this but I can't seem to find anything?

BeautifulSoup

It should work like this:
youtube.com/user/1/
You scrape the page and then it moves to
youtube.com/user/2/

If you could find the solution in beautiful soup that would be cool :)
etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
while scraping:
    for i in range(amount_of_scrapes):
        scrape(f"youtube.com/user/{i+1}/")
    scraping = False
```

This is just an example but correct implemented it should work

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.
Would anyone else like to expand on this?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```py
last_page_num = # set the last page number here

scraped_data = []
for page_num in range(1, last_page_num + 1):
    url = f'youtube.com/user/{page_num}/'
    try:

        ################## SCRAPE URL ################## 
   
        ############ APPEND TO scraped_data ############

    except Exception as err: 
        print(f'unable to scrape {url}\n{str(err)}')
        # break # if you want to stop after first error

################# SAVE scraped_data #################
```

Comment: Interesting, thank you for responding. I appreciate it!

Comment: what if you don't know the last page number?

Comment: @Omar if you know how to detect the last page, add a conditional `break` for it; otherwise, you can set a number you can be sure is the more than the maximum page number, and then either: accept that all iterations after the last page are going to be wasted (and also will print at least 2 lines of error messages each time), **OR** uncomment the `break` in `except:..` (if you're not expecting errors before reaching last page), **OR** add a counter in `except:..` and `break` after a certain number of errors